# Spring : Can a class be both @Document and @Table

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, cassandra

I am using spring in MVC context. I am working with Cassandra and MonogDB. For the project, I have to make my models and dao classes compatible with both databases. Is it possible to have the same model class be `@Document` and also be `@Table`? Will spring be able to make the distinction at runtime?

For example, for mongo i will have

```
@Document
public class Book{

    @Id
    private String uniqueId;

    /*Other details*/
}
```

and for cassandra i will have

```
@Table
public class Book{

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "uniqueId", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private String uniqueId;

    /*Other details*/
}
```

can i have something like

```
@Table
@Document
public class Book{

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "uniqueId", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    @Id
    private String uniqueId;

    /*Other details*/
}
```

Comment: You should always try it first yourself before asking. This particular use case should work, though

Comment: ah, ok. i'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if you have the correct repository configurations. For specific details, please see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very much possible. One classic example is when you want to have different datasources in your local/test and production environments. You could use Mongo in your test environment and MySql in production. So you could use both `spring-data-mongo` and `javax.persistance` annotations simultaneosly