# Multiple Database Type Support for an Entity in SpringBoot

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa

Team

I'm building a spring boot application that can support multiple DBs either Cassandra, CouchDB or DynamoDB based on the configuration in application.yml.

My entity class has annotations that are specific to Cassandra and the annotations for DynamoDB are different. For eg. DynamoDB has @DynamoDBTable for Table and Cassandra has @org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table annotations.

The problem is that I would like to use a single entity object irrespective of the DB type because the entity is referred from multiple places in the application. What is the best design pattern to implement this?

**In case of Cassandra -**

```
package com.abc;

@Table("Cart")
    public class Cart  {

        @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        protected String id;

        @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
        private String userId;

        @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
        private String skuId;
```

**In case of DynamoDB -**

```
   @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Cart")
    public class Cart  {

        @DynamoDBHashKey
        @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
        protected String id;

        private String userId;

        private String skuId;
```

Thanks
AA

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908365/spring-can-a-class-be-both-document-and-table/47909277#47909277 . This holds good for any databases

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create an intermediary object which can act as a bridge between your application logic and database ORM.

You can create a helper function which populate those fields.

```
class CartDAO  {

    private String id;
    private String userId;
    private String skuId;

    // Getters & Setters

}

class CartService{

    CartDAO fetchFromDynamoDB(String Id)
    {
        // Fetch from DB
        // Create CartDAO from that object
        // Return CartDAO
    }

    CartDAO fetchFromCassandra(String Id)
    {
        // Fetch from DB
        // Create CartDAO from that object
        // Return CartDAO
    }
}
```

Now you can use CartDAO seamlessly in your application logic.

Comment: Is there a cleaner approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Option 1:

Simply put the required annotation of both MongoDB and Cassandra.
Each annotation will have there own package and definition. So provide the required definition.

Option 2:

As defined by snk01, you can use that approach as well.

Here i am assuming that you are writing the persistence layer for each database seperately.